# How to link JS function to a Bootstrap Text Input Modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a basic Bootstrap Modal on my page with a text input field, which I will want to trigger upon clicking the "Report A Bug" button shown above.

```
   <div class="btn-group" id="exampleModal" role="group">
    <button id="myBtnToReportABug" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Report A Problem </button>
  </div>

   
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Please Provide A Short Description Of The Issue</h5>
            <div class="input-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Report</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However I'm not sure of the best way to trigger it in Javascript. As you can see project already has a call to a modal, but its not a modal that is created in the HTML as I have with this 'Report A Bug' one.

```
 $("#myBtnToReportABug").click(() => openModalPopup(cCenterUrl));
```

**EDIT**

Tried the Data Target method as mentioned below due to it's simplicity, but my Modal is not hidden nor does the click of the button trigger the modal to appear, any ideas?

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button id="myBtnToCcenter" type="button" target= '_blank' class="btn btn-primary"> Open CCenter </button>
      <button id="myBtnToReportABug" type="button" target= '_blank' class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-report"> Report A Problem </button>
    </div>

<div class="modal-report" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Report A Bug</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Report</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: From what i can see here (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo) which looks to be similar to your code, in the bootstrap example you have the data-target in the button but you need to give the modal div the same ID, see if that works?

Comment: @Liam I've tried that method, but have had some issues. Added an edit with the code.

Comment: Try changing the modal back to its normal class like before and this time add an ID to it, i'll write it out.

So the button will look like this


`<button id="myBtnToReportABug" type="button" target= '_blank' class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bugReport"> Report A Problem </button>`


and the modal will look like this:


`<div class="modal" id="bugReport" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">`

See what that does for me.

Answer (score 0):

You trigger the modal with: `data-target="#exampleModal"`

Then you also need the right modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Programmatically you have to do this

`$('#exampleModalLabel').modal('show');`

You previously need to initialize it with show: false so it won't show until you manually do it.

`$('#exampleModalLabel').modal({ show: false})`

Where exampleModalLabel is the id of the modal container.

Comment: It is my understanding that you don't need the JS though, your description at the start should be enough (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes) as with bootstrap you can just trigger the modal with data attributes. Or if the OP would like to use JS then they dont need to use the data attributes.

Edit: also the JS woud be ('#exampleModal') as that's the ID you have given the modal?

Comment: right! you have two ways. one via the bootstrap framework data-target Tag and one programmatically ```$('#exampleModalLabel').modal('show');```

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I thought you were saying in your answer you needed both.

Comment: unfortunately, the colleague who asked the question above forgot the id selector in the modal. that's why it can't work.

this is missing in the modal div tag id="exampleModal" with the class modal.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I commented on the original question with! :)